# How can I pass command-line arguments to AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly?

Tags: .net, command-line, appdomain, command-line-arguments, .net-assembly

I'm trying to run an assembly (.NET 3.5, Windows Form application) using `AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly()`.

The reason I need to do this is so that I can change the application base directory and probing paths (ie. the probing/dependency path is the *parent* folder of the application so an app.config won't work to my knowledge)

However, I can't seem to pass command-line arguments.

I'm trying to execute the method like this:

```
myAppDomain.ExecuteAssembly("c:\folder\application\application.exe", Nothing,
    New String() { "argument 1", "argument 2", "argument 3" })
```

However, my application does NOT receive the arguments.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the relevant code from application.exe?

Comment: Sure, but I am literally just doing a For Each s As String In My.Application.CommandLineArgs, Console.WriteLine(s)... (you get the idea)

Comment: Are you starting the same application and is it marked as a "single-instance" application?

Comment: application.exe is being executed from a different assembly (let's call it main_program.exe) - also, I've tried running other assemblies using ExecuteAssembly and none of them seem to receive any command-line arguments when I use the ExecuteAssembly() method.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to parse the command-line arguments that are passed to the static void Main(string[] args) function instead of using Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small [a .NET 3.5 solution](https://github.com/zippy1981/AppDomainArguments) with two executables that does exactly what you are trying to do successfully and it works. I don't know what I did different than you.